# how to extract an value in datatable column

Tags: asp.net

datatable name  : images
under that i have  one   column called  image

```
under(image column) i have   values 
image1-school
image2-college
image3-mba
```

Now i need  to extract only school college mba values  from that  column
  and  bind these  values in check box list

how  to achive this one

thank  you

Answer (score 0):

```
// first I need to create a match to see if the input string is in the corrent form
Match match = Regex.Match("image1-school", @"^image\d-(.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
// the parenthesis in the Regular Expression meeans the content must be place in a group
// as groups are 1 based, the first group is group[1]
if (match.Success)
{
     // this string will have the value of whatever was within the parenthesis
     string theStringYouWant = Regex.Match("image1-school", @"^image\d-(.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
}
```